# Client/Server Model C#

Tags: c#, client-server

I have written a sample client and server. The server keeps on listening while client connects, sends requests and then disconnects. I have a scenerio when the client connects to the server and before sending requests the server is shutdown forcefully or by any means. My question is how can I handle this? Can I keep the server from disconnecting unless it notifies its connected clients? Can I write such a method? How?

EDIT: by server and client i mean server and client applications I have written my self
Thanks

Comment: What if the scenario includes a sysadmin forcefully terminating the server service? You certainly can't program around that.

Comment: Worse case scenario: the server loses power. How will it ever send a signal? Clients should always be very fault tolerant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please clarify your situation. The

> server

means your server application or the physical server itself? If the server means the o/s itself, then nothing you can do except to perform a thorough software and hardware troubleshooting.

UPDATE:

Ok, if that is your application problem, then you can try to implement Try..Catch statement in your code and learn more for the exception being raised.

The point is that, you must prevent an exception in the first place rather than seeking solution when exception happens.

Since you are in control for both server and client application, you can use a comet approach to monitor the server application status, ie the server still running, or had shutdown.

For more information about the concept of comet approach, here is the link: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/CometAsync.aspx

Comment: my server application, as mentioned in my question

Comment: I have already used try-catches, i only want to notify my client application that server has shutdown or disconnected.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunate short answer: no. Lots of things can forcefully and unexpectedly shut down your server -- whether it be a network error, a system administrator, or a state-wide power failure.

The best you can do is ensure your client is able to handle sudden server disconnections.

Comment: How will the client know? I mean I am catching exceptions that tell about disconnection but is there any way I can set a variable or something that can help?

Comment: Help with what? If your server unexpectedly fails, you can't possibly expect it :) all you'll get on the client side is a sudden disconnection. That's how you know: the server wasn't supposed to disconnect, yet it did! The client should always know what to expect from the server. Use headers that specify the length of data to be expected, use goodbye-messages that tell a client disconnecting is OK, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything you can do if the server is forcefully shut down.  The best you can do is make sure the client checks to make sure the server is still up before it sends any commands.  This will at least prevent the client from crashing.

If your client is always connected and able to receive commands from the server there is nothing stopping you from sending some kind of command to the client if the server is shut down in an orderly fashion.